# El controller no recibe un argumento laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

En la vista:

```
{!! Form::model($evento,['route'=>['eventos.update',$evento->id], 'method'=>'PUT','files'=> true])!!}
@include('eventos.form.editar')
{!! Form::submit('Editar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

En el controller:

```
    public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $evento = Evento::find($id);
    $evento->fill($request->all());
    $evento->save();
    Session::flash('mensaje','Evento editado Correctamente');
    return Redirect::to('eventos');
}
```

En la route:

```
Route::resource('eventos','EventoController');
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
FatalThrowableError in EventoController.php line 54:
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\EventoController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected
```

El id parece que lo envia pero el request no... no se porque pasa eso...

Comment: En vez de esto: $request->all() Intenta con esto  $request->only(['mi_campo1', 'mi_campo2, mi_campo3'])   https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-fill-a-model-when-request-has-too-many-fields

Comment: no que va, me da el mismo error, parece que envia uno solo pero el request parace que no...

Comment: Otra opción es que guardes indivudualmente cada campo en tu modelo como acá: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436164/save-form-data-in-laravel

Comment: Asi fue que probe realmente, pero nada

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes hacer es hacer un dd() o var_dump en donde recoges tus valores de tu formulario para saber si realmente estás recibiendo esos valores.

Comment: No que va, ni siquiere llega al controlador, no me permite ver que esta mandando.

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionar, por si a alguien le sirve o quiere mejorar mi solución. Por alguna razón el controlador no esta recibiendo la variable $id, así que lo que hice fue crear un input tipo hidden con el valor del id del registro y con un $request tomar ese id y buscar el registro para luego poder editar.

Quedo asi:

Controlador:

```
    public function update(Request $request)
{
    $evento = Evento::find($request->eventId);
    $evento->nombre = $request->nombre;
    $evento->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
    $evento->img = $request->img;
    $evento->fecha = $request->fecha;
    $evento->lugar = $request->lugar;
    $evento->precio = $request->precio;
    $evento->estatus = $request->estatus;
    $evento->descuento_registro = $request->descuento_registro;
    $evento->slug = $request->slug;
    $evento->tipo_evento = $request->tipo_evento;
    $evento->evento_privado = $request->evento_privado;
    $evento->save();
    Session::flash('mensaje','Evento editado Correctamente');
    return Redirect::to('eventos');


}
```

Vista:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{$evento->id}}" name="eventId">
```

Comment: Al no tener ningún input en el formulario que tenga el name `id` con el valor correspondiente, ni pasarlo por `url` no llegará al controlador. Esta es la razón por la que el controlador no recibía la variable. En el momento que has puesto un input con el `id` ya puedes capturar este `id` por `$request`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que primero debes inyectar las dependencias y luego el resto de parámetros.

Tu ejemplo:

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    //
}
```

Debería quedar así:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}
```

Documentación:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers